# Validating with LDAP

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

I have a web application which is runs on  Weblogic.Normally, when a user accesses my web application using a browser,
the web application presents them with a login page where they are asked to enter their username and password. 
I have to authenticate them against LDAP Directory and then it should present the requested resource.
The userid and password used here are same as  Windows NT user id and password.
I am able to connect LDAP, but validating password is not working.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

check your server is that LDAP v3 or LDAP v2 ? And when you try to connect ldap, connect with appropriate version.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options here:

1. Bind using the user's credentials. If the bind is successful, their password is correct.
2. Depending on your directory server (it seems you're using AD) and the associated policies you may or may not be able to read the password attribute. This is very uncommon however and most likely the password will be hashed anyway.